# maven transitive dependencies conflicts

Tags: maven

My project depends on libraries A and B at the same time. A and B both depend on a transitive dependency C, but under different versions. Is it possible to include different versions of lib C and force lib A and B to depend on their own dependency?

Comment: You can only have a single version of lib C. You can decide which one by defining the version in your own project directly.

Comment: either lib A or B will not work with another version of dependency C, that's why I have to include two different versions

Comment: That's not solvable. The problem in the end is having two different versions on the classpath. The order on the classpath would decide which version will be used. Apart from that Maven will resolve into a single dependency. The only way is to either upgrade A or B to different version which use the same version of C.. No other way is possible.